# Transliteration- Is it possible to transliterate filenames (and update the DB) after files have been uploaded?

Tags: files

I have a website that allows users to upload pictures.  To reduce the amount of space used by pictures files on my site, I attempted to use [a script to remove orphaned files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/69036/5147).  However, this script chokes on Unicode file names; there are dozens of pictures with Unicode file names on my site:

> query:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's Adorable Kitty EDIT.jpg'' at line 1

I have enabled the [Transliteration](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module so that new files will not have this problem.  However, what can I do about the old files?  Is there a way to change their names and update the Drupal DB?  I am willing to do this manually if necessary, but I don't know how to approach this.

**EDIT**: Upon closer inspection, the problem is not unicode, it's the quote marks in the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am able to tell, the script works OK with Unicode.

But the script doesn't sanitize the file names, and that is what invalidates the query.

It could be a a lot worse. If somebody uploads an image named `image'); DROP TABLE *;--.jpg`, and you use that script, they would erase your site (as shown in the XKCD cartoon below):

[image]

Source: xkdc - [Exploits of a mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

I would strongly advice postponing the use of that script until somebody who understands database security has cleaned it up.

Suggestion: hand edit the file names with quotes in them by removing the quotes, and edit the corresponding names in table `file_managed`.

I am also puzzled that the Drupal file upload module does not sanitize file names by not permitting quotes in file names.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working by editing the filenames manually.